# How do I determine whether a database connection is read/write or read-only in GRDB?

Tags: grdb

In GRDB I can create read-only database connections with

```
try dbPool.read { db in
```

I can create read-write database connections with

```
try dbPool.write { db in
```

In each case I can call a function from within the closure using db as an argument. In GRDB read-only database connections can run in parallel in different threads. Write database connections block the database.

I have a pattern I would like to use in some functions:

- Select a record filtered on some attributes.
- If a record is found, return it.
- If no record is found, create a default placeholder record with those attributes.
- If the db is read-write, save the default placeholder and return it.
- If the db is read-only, just return the placeholder

Is there a way to determine if the db is read-only? Looking through the reference documentation at http://groue.github.io/GRDB.swift/docs/4.1/Classes/Database.html, I don't see a simple way to determine this aside from error handling.

I could just attempt to save in the function and catch the error if the db is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to determine if the db is read-only?

No, there isn't any public way to get this information. It would be possible, but the feature request hasn't shown up yet.

> I could just attempt to save in the function and catch the error if the db is read-only.

Correct.

> I have a pattern I would like to use in some functions [...]

The pattern you describe looks like a premature optimization for a plain simple write. Do you notice actual performance problems?